# Make Android AVD running on host visible on Vmware virtual machine guest system

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device

So, my scenario:

- I have Android development environmet already configured on my Linux machine + some avd emulators from Google, running very smooth
- Now I need to develop some app on Xamarin. I'm doing it on my Vmware Player virtual machine, with Windows 7 as guest

I want to still use avd emulator running on my host machine (Linux) and make it visible for guest system, that runs Visual Studio + Xamarin. Do you have any idea how to make it possible? I am actually unable to run any emulator on Windows 7 guest (even if, performance will be slow), so I'm stuck and forced to use physical phone.